# Wordpress Page Content not showing

Tags: wordpress

I've recently started a new website with Wordpress through blue host.
I'm completely new to this and had never even heard of either of these programs up until last week.

I downloaded a theme from Mojo marketplace linked to blue host called Solstice. I've managed to make some customer changes and get some pictures and pages and post headers on there.

The only trouble I'm having right now is that I've wrote text in the About us section but it doesn't show up on the website. I haven't downloaded any plugins yet and the template it still set to default.

I have tried googling the answer but not had much luck. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[www.2lostbuffaloes.com](http://www.2lostbuffaloes.com)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

As Naveed mentioned, the text color is white, over white background, that's why you can't see it. If you add to your css this rule:

```
body {
    color #000000;
}
```

The text should appear.

You will probably also want to add white to the text color of the footer:

```
.footer-top, .footer-top a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Yes when I press CTRL and A the text comes up! Do I add the CSS code in the top box or the bottom custom box?

Comment: @NatashaJNicholls I don't have a Blue Host WP installation to test, but apparently you could do it by "using Jetpack and the Custom CSS feature": https://bluehost.blog/open-source/adding-your-touch-wordpress-theme-2676/

Comment: I've added the Jetpack plugin and i've typed in the above code to the Custom CSS but still nothing.

Comment: @NatashaJNicholls It's difficult to know what could be the problem, as we don't have many details on what you tried. Have you seen this page: https://jetpack.com/support/custom-css/ ? It's a walk-through to the Jetpack CSS feature. Please, let me know if this helps.

Comment: @NatashaJNicholls Did you contact the guys from blue host? I'm sure they will walk you through adding your css! Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

In style sheet, you need to do

```
body{
    color : #000000;
}
```

Right now its white color for text, if you do control A on about us page you will see all text.

Comment: Yes when I press CTRL and A the text comes up! Do I add the CSS code in the top box or the bottom custom box?

Comment: Go to admin end -> Appearance -> editor -> select stylesheet.css in right sidebar and then find body{color:#ffffff;} ... replace these 6 times 'f' with  zero '0'

Comment: The closest thing i can find that is...body {
  background: #fff; /* Fallback for when there is no custom background color defined. */
}

Comment: ok you can add after semi-colon 
    color:#000000 !important;

Comment: OK, contact me at skype (naveedramzan)

Comment: Or go to stylesheet.css and find .entry-content ... add "color:#000 !important;"

Comment: Add it this?...      .entry-content {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}                                                                                                                           Any {} needed?

Comment: Dear you need to add this only 
.entry-content { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }